# Need batch file to restart an app every day automatically

Tags: batch-file

Need batch file to restart an app every day automatically. Normally, when I restart the program, its shows a popup to enter the machine number. The default is 1. After that it works. I tried to create a .bat file to restart the app, but it stops at that pop up and again we have to manually enter the machine number and press OK. How do I create a .bat file that chooses the default machine number and start the app every day?

```
@echo off
:loop
start "Queue Tokens Display" "C:\Users\MEDIEXPRESS\Desktop\Display\Queue.Tokens.Display.application"
timeout /t 10 >null
taskkill /f /im "Queue.Tokens.Display.exe" >nul
goto loop
```

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with GUI applications.  You will need to use a different scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a batch file containing this

```
taskkill /IM Application.exe
start C:/Path/To/Application.exe
```

and a scheduled task to run that batch script every day.
this can also be done via commandline, the task name is Restart application and it runs at midnight.(C:/Path/To/batch.bat is where you would put your bat file location)

```
    SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN “RestartApplication” /TR “C:/Path/To/batch.bat” /ST 00:00
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the need to manually enter a number via a GUI in the OP's program.

Comment: @TripeHound did not see literally one word in the description when i posted my answer, the title only appeared.
Yeah man theres literally close to no way possible to doing what he has asked unless he modifies the sourcecode of the application itself